# Is there a CM designated to be responsible for the community?

Tags: discussion

I'm missing a figure of a CM here to help the site with some guidelines.

When StackOverflow in Portuguese was launched, we had [Gabe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) fully designated to take care of that community, will Portuguese Language have one as well? Who?

Comment: Acho que é o JNat o nosso CM aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho que não..

Comment: @VictorStafusa -- JNat is not a Community Manager (he and I are Ops Specialists), but he will likely be around a bit to help with the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) generally watches over very new sites and helps them get through the early stages, up 'till public beta. He's on vacation this week, unfortunately, but that doesn't mean you're left out in the cold all on your own :)

Some things to note ..

- Very, *very* few of us speak Portuguese. Gabe is quite busy with SOPT, Jnat is quite busy helping users that contact us. If it's important, it needs to be in English.
- When you post in Portuguese, it's *nice* if you can provide an English translation, so that we can at least look in on what the community is discussing. Machine translations are *fine*.

That said, I'm going to ask [good King Icky Socks](https://twitter.com/dhekke) (AKA Gabe) to look in on things while Robert is away, as he's *uniquely* qualified to infurate you far better than Robert could :D

Comment: "Machine translations are fine" Seriously!? Hopefully only in meta, right?

Comment: We already have a number of meta posts. While we're [waiting](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-try-to-populate-this-site-with-questions), this site is filling up with many questions, posted just because they haven't been posted here... (See also [About superficial questions](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/sobre-quest%C3%B5es-superficiais).) In the meantime, meta fills up with Portuguese posts and we don't even know whether we officially should keep meta posts in English. Could someone maybe address some of these issues?

Comment: (In other words, what were you thinking when you gave everyone early access to an empty site? It's like leaving a bunch of kids with a big chocolate cake on a white tablecloth and coming back _a week_ later... ;)

Comment: @Earthliŋ I should say that comparing our users with kids isn't flattering, but damn if it isn't accurate... :D

Comment: @Gabe Tongues in both cheeks! I'm not intending to insult anyone, of course.

Comment: Usually sites get out of beta in 7 days. Are we extending our private beta phase? Can we please have an official communication from an employee like there was [here](http://meta.startups.stackexchange.com/q/49/60)?

Comment: @Math The default case is now to let the private betas go the full **two weeks.** It used to be that we let them go a week with the optional second week if they needed it, but it was rare that one week was enough, so we switched over to a standard two-week private beta.

Comment: @RobertCartaino thank you for replying. Perhaps you also will enjoy answering this one: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/135/3 :)

Comment: @Math Thanks. Answered well [here](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/135/quantos-dias-ficaremos-em-beta-privado#comment401_136) where I commented about the standard two-week private beta to clarify.