# Who are the moderators here?

Tags: discussion, support

Sure, under the logic of Stack Exchange and according to the reputation earned on sites, each one of us acts as a moderator with the appropriate level of restrictions and control. Together we form a large, mutually supported community.

We work for our enjoyment, thus taking part in this "game".

But who are the actual moderators? What is the role of these moderators? Can any user become a moderator?

---

É claro que na lógica dos sites do Stack Exchange e de acordo com a reputação conquistada nos sites, cada um de nós age como um moderador que possui as devidas restrições e controle. Todos juntos formamos uma grande comunidade, onde nos ajudamos mutuamente.

Trabalhamos por prazer, para participar do jogo.

Mas quem são os moderadores de fato?
Quais são as funções dos moderadores?
Qualquer usuário pode ser tornar um moderadores?

Comment: Cross-duplicate. :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: Isso, moderador.

Comment: Vi que foi classificada como duplicada, mas existe resposta em português?

Comment: @DenisHenriqueCaixeta Não é duplicada, é apenas cross-duplicada. Não é um motivo para fechar a pergunta sequer. Se o problema está na barreira linguística, com certeza que pode alguém fazer uma resposta.

Comment: Related: [Accepting nominations — Who should moderate this site?](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/154/3)

Comment: Hello there! Can you please add an English translation to what you've said in Portuguese, like in the other meta posts?

Comment: Of course that in the logic of the Stack Exchange sites and according with the earned reputation in the sites, each of us act like a moderator who have the proper restrictions and control. All of us together form a huge community, where we help each other. 

We work for pleasure, to make part of the game.

But who are the moderators indeed? What are the functions of the moderators? Any user can become a moderator?

Comment: At this very moment: [Earthliŋ, tchrist and JorgeB](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/169/please-welcome-your-new-moderators) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enquanto uma resposta mais completa não aparece, a sequência é mais ou menos assim:

- primeiro um ou mais Community Manager faz a moderação do site; ver [Is there a CM designated to be responsible for the community?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/44/135)
- depois quando o site já está em pleno movimento, a comunidade [sugere](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/154) e a empresa (ou serão os CMs?)  [designa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452/aproveite-a-copa-com-modera%C3%A7%C3%A3o) moderadores [*pro-tempore*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_tempore) enquanto não se convocam eleições
- e finalmente, depois que sai do beta público, chega o momento em que acontece a [eleição de verdade pela comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4011/resultado-da-elei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-moderador-2015?lq=1) e temos a primeira leva de Moderadores Oficiais

---

<sup><sup>Thanks to MarcosSartorato for the translation</sup></sup>

While a more complete answer doesn't appear, things happen in this sequence:

- First one or more Community Managers make the site moderation; see [Is there a CM designated to be responsible for the community?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/44/135)
- After when the site is active, the community [suggests](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/154) and the company (or will be the CM's?) designate [pro-tempore](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_tempore) moderators while the elections don't happen;
- And finally, after that the public beta ends, we have the [real election by the community](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4011/resultado-da-elei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-moderador-2015?lq=1) and we have the first "wave" of Official Moderators.

Comment: Só um aparte, só há eleições depois de sair de beta publico.

Comment: blz, corrigido, vlw

Comment: Can you please add an English translation to what you've said above in Portuguese, like in other meta posts?

Comment: While a more complete answer doesn't appear, things happen in this sequence:

1 - First one or more Community Managers make the site moderation; see Is there a CM designated to be responsible for the community?

2 - After when the site is active, the community suggests and the company (or will be the CM's?) designate pro-tempore moderators while the elections don't happen;

3 - And finally, after that the public beta ends, we have the real election by the community and we have the first "wave" of Official Moderators

Comment: @MarcosSartorato, thanks a bunch, included.