# Accepting nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, we will be appointing some provisional Moderators to fill that role.

We need your help. Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

### The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation.
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> `##[username](<main profile link>)`
> `##[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>)`
>
> `Notes:`
>
> `<why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>`
>
> `---`
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> `I accept/decline this nomination`
>
> `I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are`…
>
> `etc.`

Comment: Welcome Robert :)

Comment: Só tem gente boa! Assim fica complicado não votar em alguém!

Answer (score 21):

## Jorge B.

[image: profile for Jorge B. at Portuguese Language Stack Exchange, Q&A for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language]

[image: profile for Jorge B. at Portuguese Language Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language]

[profile for Jorge B. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2035158.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/2035158)

I would like to nominate Jorge B. as pro tempore moderator of the Portuguese Language community.

He is one of the most active and excited users and I pretty sure that if he accepts the indication and is chosen moderator he will do a very great job pushing the community forward.

Probably most of users here don't know him because it's a new community, that's why I'd like to explain that my indication is because of his good historic at [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). There, he is an avid user since a long time ago and is very valuable to the community.

<sub>Indicated by [Math](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/3/math)</sub>

---

I accept your nomination @Math! [Thank you!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4162/usu%c3%a1rio-tentando-retaliar-com-votos-negativos-suspeita/4163#comment11630_4163)

I'm Jorge and I'm from Portugal. I love my native language and I always try to speak and write Portuguese perfectly. This site is my opportunity to help other people to learn Portuguese and **finally** I can clarify my doubts too.

Who knows me from [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), knows that I try to maintain the site clean and help new users to create good questions.

We actually need more experts in the site like professors and writers. I'll try to encourage some professors and writers who I know to use PL.

[PT] *Divertires-te até à p*ta da loucura: eis a tua maior prova de sanidade.* - [Pedro Chagas Freitas](http://www.pedrochagasfreitas.com/)

[EN] *Have fun until the f***ing madness: that your greatest test of sanity.*

Answer (score 21):

## Earthliŋ

[image: profile for Earthliŋ at Portuguese Language Stack Exchange, Q&A for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language]

[image: profile for Earthliŋ at Portuguese Language Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language]

[profile for Earthliŋ on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1244118.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1244118)

I would like to nominate Earthliŋ as pro tempore moderator of the Portuguese Language community.

He is a real language enthusiast. As far as I can tell he speaks German, English, Japanese, Portuguese and probably some other languages that nobody better than him can say which. He is also very very participative member of several different stack exchange communities, which is a great indicator he knows very well how the system works.

Also, he is the one who proposed this community, so I believe he has big interest in seeing it getting always bigger and better. His actual position of moderator on Sustainable Living certainly counts in favor of his experience, and I hope it doesn't count against when it comes to available time to moderate one more community :)

<sub>Indicated by [Math](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/3/math)</sub>

---

`I accept this nomination`

Thank you for the nomination. I'm Earthliŋ and started (substance-ab)using the SE network on Japanese.SE. (I'm no programmer.)

I've seen that the SE system has a lot to offer for language sites, which was my motivation for restarting the Portuguese language proposal. (But judging from the first two weeks in private beta, I also noticed that there are large cultural differences between Japanese and Portuguese language learners, so I wouldn't be looking to turn Portuguese.SE into a Portuguese version of Japanese.SE.)

I'm still learning Portuguese, but I understand most of written (Brazilian) Portuguese (if not so much colloquial language). I'm a native speaker of German (so no Brazilian jokes), but I also feel quite comfortable around English.

My other moderator duties are, well, moderate and I don't expect to be swamped with SE work. (Sustainability.SE has 0.6 questions / day, flags every other week or so.)

It's become my second nature to clean-up/flag comments, edit and retag as I surf the SE network, so having moderator privileges would save other moderators the trouble. (I'm no radicalist, though, so don't worry, I won't leave this site like a withered tree.)

In any case, I'm really excited for this site and I will be doing my part to keep this site active and flourishing, as moderator or otherwise. The last thing I would want is to make this site into my little pet project. But seeing the enthusiasm of the other users I'm sure this site will do well and a number of other users would make great moderators, too!

Falou!

<sub>Small print: I live in Brazil and I'm very unlikely to be online GMT 1-9.</sub>

Answer (score 18):

### [tchrist](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/38)

[image]

[image]

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/216196.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/216196)

*Notes*

This user has extensive experience on the SE network's other language sites and [meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/153355/tchrist); is fluent in both Portuguese and English (as far as I can tell); and has been active during the beta, contributing well-received questions and answers on both the main and meta sites.

If he is inclined towards taking on the role, I think he'd make a great moderator for this site.

---

#### I accept this nomination.

Thanks for the nomination, Frank. I’ve been an active SE member going on five years now so am well acquainted with its machinery. I live in Colorado and am generally active on the SE network between 12:00 and 02:00 UTC.  Yes, I’m a morning person. :)

I’m a native speaker of English who grew up speaking Spanish as a second language. My background is in computer programming and Romance languages; my first degree is in Spanish. Portuguese was my fourth Romance language learned, although in practice I’m stronger in it than in anything but Spanish. I’ve worked in both Brazil and Portugal several times each, but I know Portugal better having lived in neighboring Spain during college but taking holidays in Portugal. As such, reading Portuguese comes naturally to me but my writing is prone to the same little glitches as any other Spanish speaker’s would be.

I’m excited about the enthusiasm and courteousness shown by the community during the private beta, so I’ve been working to bring more Portuguese language experts to the site. I spend several hours a day the SE network volunteering as a janitor, cleaning up and retagging posts that need it and running the review queues. I believe every SE community should develop its own character and culture, which is why its beta period is so important.  That also means that a moderator’s hand should be light and mostly unseen, handling the exceptions while encouraging community growth until it mostly runs itself.

**I endorse this nomination.** (by Centaurus)

I've been observing [**tchrist**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/38/tchrist)'s actions in another SE site ([**EL&U**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist)) for almost two years and I don't hesitate to endorse his nomination for a pro tempore moderator.  I have observed the following qualities during that period of time and, imho they are the essential qualities a moderator should have.

- Tchrist is one of the most active members on [**EL&U**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) with more than 1300 answers so far.
- He has been an everyday contributor at that site, since the early days (almost five years now)
- He has the fourth highest reputation (72.6 K) in what is one of the busiest SE sites, in addition to holding 460 badges (16 gold badges)
- He is a highly knowledgeable fellow, speaks several languages fluently, including Portuguese, and has lived in Portuguese speaking countries for a period of time.
- He understands perfectly how SE works, what it does and does not need, and has a lot of experience in dealing with problems, animosities and trouble makers.
- Displays sensible and sound judgement.
- If there was only one position available, I wouldn't hesitate to say he is the man.

**Centaurus**.

Answer (score 13):

## [bfavaretto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/80/bfavaretto)

[image]


[image: profile for bfavaretto at Portuguese Language Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language]

[profile for bfavaretto on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/437871.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/437871.png)

*Notes*

bfavaretto is one of the top users of the site, a native speaker of (Brazilian) Portuguese and fluent in English (as far as I can tell) and has been very active during the private beta, not only in answering (and asking) questions, but also leaving helpful comments, editing & reviewing posts, etc. Apart from the data, it's my personal impression that he would be a great moderator.

Also, he currently is one of the moderators of Stack Overflow em Português, served both as a pro-term moderator and being now an elected one.

---

**`Thank you for the nomination, but I can't`**

Thank you Earthliŋ and everyone who supported my nomination. This site has a personal meaning to me: it reconnects me with my background in Linguistics. So I want to participate as much as I can, I want the site to grow and be a place where people can always learn from, myself included.

However at the moment I cannot commit to PL as much as the moderator position requires. I know it's a small site and the volume of posts and flags should be low for a while, but I believe being a moderator is much more than handling flags and keeping an eye on the content. A moderator has to constantly discuss the site with the community, think about where it comes from and where it's going, suggest and handle other people's suggestions, and so on. A moderator needs a high *mental* level of commitment apart from the more mechanical tasks, and that's what I can't provide right now.

We are lucky to have many other users who will be great moderators, I'm sure. Maybe I will be allowed to join them when our first election comes :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Guilherme Nascimento](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/8/guilherme-nascimento)

[image]

[image: profile for Guilherme Nascimento at Portuguese Language Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language]


[profile for Guilherme Nascimento on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1647724.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1647724)

I would like to nominate Guilherme Nascimento, who is currently our top user, and is clearly very enthusiastic about this site. Guilherme is also very active in [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), and on its meta too, where he is always seeking to learn the finer details of the SE engine. He is always nice to other users, but doesn't refrain from stating his opinions, and that, I believe, is a great quality for a moderator to have.

---

## I can't at the moment :(

I thank those who remembered and *upvoted* for me, although much will collaborate with the site.

## I wish success to all!