# Please welcome your new moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation

First off, thanks to everyone who participated at the [moderator nomination](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site) meta post!

Throughout the beta, we need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us ensure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: tchrist]
[image: JorgeB]
[image: ANeves]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, almost certainly. There are many members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition who are not moderators. My inability to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**

I may also eventually be contacting additional users to fill more pro tem moderator slots, on an as-needed basis.

Most of all, please be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Let's also take a moment to thank these past users, who've stepped up to help moderate this community in the past:

[image: Earthliŋ]

Comment: Congratulations for the new mods!

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: Parabéns aos new mods. :D

Comment: Welcome to all new mods! Good luck!